# Widget-based web framework in Python (similar to vaadin, GWT or zkoss)

Tags: python, justpy

I am basically from Java, but I need to use Python for a new project. I prefer widget based web framework like zkoss, vaadin, GWT etc.

Does python has widget based framework?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Muntjac](http://www.muntjac.org/), it is a semi-automatic translation of vaadin, and depending on your needs about python you just can use jython inside vaadin, but you will lost the 3th party c extesions to python...

Answer (score 1):

[Pyjs](https://github.com/pyjs/pyjs) is a GWT port in python, and should do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Note that [Vaadin can be used with Python](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Using%20Python).

Answer (score 1):

As of 2022, [Justpy](https://justpy.io) seems to be the only one which is still actively maintained.

Answer (score 0):

[lona](https://github.com/lona-web-org) is an option as well as all the candidates in the [purepython-list](https://may69.com/purepython/)

If you are just interested in the widget approach the:

- [Flask Bootstrap4 Widgets](http://q.bitplan.com:8234/widgets)
- [justpy widgets](https://pypi.org/project/pyJustpyWidgets/)

might be interesting for your. Please note that i am maintainer for [justpy](https://justpy.io/)